Variation of phase due to changes in features in the spatial domain
Let say there is a white ball at the center of a black background in a image. And i move that ball to (x,y) position. So what changes will that cause in phase and by how much. And since phase has a limit of [-pi to pi] so if i move it quite far in the same (x,y) direction from center will the phase gets wrapped around. I mean to say that if i am going upwards in image and in some point the phase become pi and then i move furthur upwards then it gets wrapped around and become -pi.
Can you also give me a formula to calculate it and make it simple to understand. I am not good with formulas
